# Use WSDL2Java generated code in Android project

Tags: android, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am starting a new Android project that will consume a service available as WSDL and REST endpoints.

It has been recommended that I use WSDL2Java to generate stubs and use this in my Android app instead of REST.

Before I go down this route and try to integrate my code, i'm just checking if it's actually possible to use the WSDL2JAVA code in Android? Will it compile?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried that and had some serious issues regarding the absence of needed libraries that seem to be absent in the Android Java implementation. Maybe I was just missing something, have you tried that, in the end?